# R: Sorting a data frame based on a vector of different length

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to sort a data frame on one of its columns, based on a vector which contains all possible elements of the column, but without duplicates. For example a table like this:

```
A   a
B   b
C   b
D   b
E   a
F   a
G   c
H   b
```

And a vector like this: `c("b", "c", "a")`

So that sorting the table on column 2 based on this vector would produce this table:

```
B   b
C   b
D   b
H   b
G   c
A   a
E   a
F   a
```

Comment: Just `df[order(match(df$V2, x)),]`

Comment: @Sotos I didn't see your comment when posting the answer

Comment: @akrun No problem. In any case I think you were 9-10 seconds earlier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` with `order`

```
df1[order(match(df1$v2, vec1)),]
#   v1 v2
#2  B  b
#3  C  b
#4  D  b
#8  H  b
#7  G  c
#1  A  a
#5  E  a
#6  F  a
```

#### data

```
vec1 <- c("b", "c", "a")
df1 < structure(list(v1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
v2 = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "c", "b")), .Names = c("v1", 
  "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```